# Best practice to display operating hours in a web design?

Tags: information-architecture, readability

1st Example:

- Monday - Friday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM

  (no longer show Saturday & Sunday as closed)

2nd Example:

- Monday - Friday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Saturday - Sunday: Closed

3rd Example:

- Monday - Friday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Saturday: Closed
- Sunday: Closed

4th Example: (left / right aligned)

- Monday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Tuesday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Wednesday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Thursday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Friday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
- Saturday: Closed
- Sunday: Closed

Also do you display the days as full vs short? (Saturday VS Sat)

Or which do you suggest is the best layout for this information?

Do you use it in all your designs

Thank you :)

Comment: Please, provide more information on context: in details data or in a list, available space, audience, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the operating hours are always the same, I would recommend using the 1st option.Keep it short and simple.
Regarding the question of the days (Saturday VS Sat) - if possible, the full word is more clear and less confusing.